Duplicating Matryoshka dolls
We start with a single doll of size $1$. Every second, independently of each other, every doll present produces a new doll of half its size with probability $\frac{1}{2}$. What is the expected size of the smallest doll after $n$ seconds?
Remark: Simulations seem to show that the expected size for large $n$ is about $2^{-kn}$ for some mysterious constant $k$ that is slightly larger than $0.77$.

As is usual with these kind of problems, a closed form answer may not be possible. The problem should be interpreted more as an open ended question asking "what can we say about the expected value"?

If you look at the logarithms (in base $2$) of the sizes of the dolls, then this is simply a branching random walk and Theorem 1.3 in these lecture notes shows that the size $X_n$ of the smallest doll satisfies $\lim_{n \to \infty} n^{-1}\log_2 X_n = -k$ almost surely, with  $k = \inf_{t > 0} t^{-1}\log(1+e^t/2)$. Numerically, one has indeed $k \approx 0.77$.

Thanks for the answer! But I think this process isn’t a random walk since it doesn’t go backward, as doll sizes don’t shrink.

did i misunderstand your claim? In mathematica, the minimum of $t^{-1}\log(1+e^t/2)$ is reported as $k=0.772908...$, which is consistent with OP's numerics.

@AccidentalFourierTransform Oops, I just graphed it and misread the labeling, sorry about that ;-)

@NateRiver Have you actually read the reference?

@MartinHairer I did, I could not find a formal definition of the branching random walk in Theorem 1.3, but from what it looks like it seems like they do consider bidirectional random walks.

@MartinHairer To be honest, the reference is written quite sketchily, and so I am unable to verify the claims made. For example I could not find a clear definition of the asymptotic velocity $V(x)$ used in Theorem 1.3. I am also not sure what the set of non-extinction is.

It also doesn’t appear to be stated whether bidirectional or unidirectional random walks are considered, or with what probability the replication happens…

@NateRiver Look at the start of Section 1.2. In your case $N \in {1,2}$ with probability $1/2$ each and, when $N=1$, $\xi_1 = 0$, while $\xi_1 = 0$ and $\xi_2 = -1$ when $N=2$. There is no constraint on the signs of the $\xi$'s, so this choice is perfectly OK.

@MartinHairer I still am having trouble deciphering the notation. Section 1.2 is written very unclearly in my opinion. It is not clear what the role of the tuple $\xi_i$ is, or what he means by “$N$ is also random”. It seems to be written very unlike the mathematical texts I am used to.

Of course, the answer is the right one if his definitions match mine, but a clearer reference would be much appreciated.

I think Theorem 2 here has the desired result.

@NateRiver In that reference the tree is assumed to be independent of the labels as far as I can see, which isn't the case in your model.
